# ANOVA or two Welch’s t test

Tags: anova, experiment-design, biostatistics

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wq8J.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wq8J.jpg)I have the results from an experiment . The groups are 
1. Saline 
2. Treatment 
3. Saline + X inhibitor 
4. Treatment + X inhibitor

My hypothesis was that treatment  acted by influencing X and inhibiting X will make Saline and treatment group same. The experiment proved my hypothesis.
My comparison groups (with each group having n=10) are *1 vs 2*   or *3 vs 4*. **I am not at all concerned about whether the mean of 3 or 4 are same as 1 or 2.**

To compare 1 vs 2 and 3 vs 4  I used two Welch’s t tests.  Is the Welchs test robust in my cases (my data is normal but may not same variance) compared to say, ANOVA

Thanks

[image: experiment results]

Answer (score 1):

As long as you provide a good strategy for multiple testing (or a very good explanation why you did not apply any), then your testing scheme should be okay. The choice of appropriate two-sample test is difficult to judge given the info in your post. If the sample size is rather small, maybe rank-tests or permutation t tests could be an option.

In general, such questions should be adressed already before running the study and are an integral part of the study protocol. Everything else would not be considered good clinical practice. From this point of view, good reviewers will hopefully be critical.